# decode eth raw transaction

Tags: raw-transaction, eip-1559

Can you decode this transaction:

**Etherscan tx:**

```
0x02f8740181f1843b9aca00851535cf027f82520894e0e5d2b4edcc473b988b44b4d13c3972cb6694cb8801ea8d467f558e1e80c001a07eb3335f4fd4de25ec3452c08882f28fb098b2eaa37a332941f918d869f5c2ada059b9d4aa997c7fa34f1b167f98a12432bb1a4a35660d723a9c19bb76b4cd025d
```

---

What I need is the decoding formula for the new eth raw transactions

Comment: Maybe add some context. Where did it come from. Is there are URL or a etherscan tx you can point to....

Comment: It's a signed tx

Answer (score 3):

You can decode your transaction here: https://rawtxdecode.in/. Here is the decoded response for your raw tx:

```
{
  "chainId": "1",
  "type": "EIP-1559",
  "valid": true,
  "hash": "0x0a7d81c47b5a298e190315eb465f73124deb68faa9fa4e5ed372911fc0051dc9",
  "nonce": "241",
  "gasLimit": "21000",
  "maxFeePerGas": "91097072255",
  "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "1000000000",
  "from": "0x5B588e36FF358D4376A76FB163fd69Da02A2A9a5",
  "to": "0xe0e5d2b4edcc473b988b44b4d13c3972cb6694cb",
  "publicKey": "0x04340f792af13fb8ebfe147c9c6c9d0b515a636501069df3b98dec3477dbcc8eb06c06ac1d5ee2895410d8641285b2365b6ed89016fd870ce74e8f6f65240932c2",
  "value": "138078072511761950",
  "v": "01",
  "r": "7eb3335f4fd4de25ec3452c08882f28fb098b2eaa37a332941f918d869f5c2ad",
  "s": "59b9d4aa997c7fa34f1b167f98a12432bb1a4a35660d723a9c19bb76b4cd025d"
}
```

Comment: How would you do the same via `ethers` or `web3` or some other lib without relying on a website?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an exact answer of the question. But it helps to prepare the ethereum transaction data EIP-1559.

We can check the hex using the broadcast transaction link provided by etherescan. It returns TxID if the raw data is valid. Otherwise shows error.

for goerlie testnet : https://goerli.etherscan.io/pushTx

Steps to prepare a EIP-1559 transaction using web3j

```
1.RawTransaction.createTransaction(chainId, nonce, gasLimit, to, value, data, maxPriorityFeePerGas, maxFeePerGas)
2. TransactionEncoder.encode(rawTransaction) // from sept1
3. Hash.sha3(encodedTx) // from step2
4. Sign the hash using private key 
5. Convert the sign to Sign.SignatureData
```

**Then Prepare the raw transaction**

```
public String prepareRawTransactionWithSignature(RawTransaction transaction, Sign.SignatureData signatureData) {

    // encode signature data
 List<RlpType> values = transaction.getTransaction().asRlpValues(signatureData);
 RlpList rlpList = new RlpList(values);
 byte[] encoded = RlpEncoder.encode(rlpList);
 if (!transaction.getType().equals(TransactionType.LEGACY)) {
        encoded = ByteBuffer.allocate(encoded.length + 1)
                .put(transaction.getType().getRlpType())
                .put(encoded)
                .array();
 }
    String serializedTxHex = Numeric.toHexString(encoded);
 log.info("Serialized tx {}", serializedTxHex);
 return serializedTxHex;
}
```